# How to end session by closing browser in angular 2 and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I tried using,

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 beforeunloadHandler($event) {
   console.log("window closed?")
 }
```

also using unload event, none of the events are working.
Plase, suggest right approach.

Comment: you cannot as this cannot be caught by Angular , you can check for tab closing but not for browser close as it can be due to any other reason too

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
ngOnDestroy() {}
```

Comment: Carsten, Thanks for the help. I added ngOnDestroy() {} into nav-bar component, which is include in all pages. but still, when I close the browser it's not calling ngOnDestroy() {} method. Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks!